# I am getting this error open /var/log/alt-php74-newrelic/newrelic-daemon.log no such file or directory

Tags: php, cron-task

When executing cron job, I'm getting this error.
**open /var/log/alt-php74-newrelic/newrelic-daemon.log: no such file or directory**

Comment: Hi Shamser, Can you add some details on what you already tried to do to resolve the issue? Is the logfile actually present? Those details can help people to provide you with a more specific answer.

Comment: Where can I find this logfile???

Comment: What is this cron job doing? If you wrote the code executed by cron please share the relevant part and describe what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @ShamserChand I do not know where you host your code, but it should on the system where php is running. With these types of errors it is always good to check if the file that is mentioned in the error (newrelic-daemon.log) is actually present at the path mentioned in the error: /var/log/alt-php74-newrelic (sometimes it can be permission issues, rather than really missing files)